# How to get the name of the DataSource referenced by my shared DataSet?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I would like to display the name of the data source used in my report, as a way to quickly identify the origin of the data.

I know I can display the name of an embedded datasource like this :

```
=DataSource("name").DataSourceReferenceString
```

However my report does not embed a datasource as I am using shared datasets.

Any ideas ? Am I "doing it wrong" ?

EDIT : The answers so far involve using the *DataSources* collection. The thing is... my report does not reference any data source whatsoever. It does reference a shared dataset, which itself references a data source.
This approach allows me to change the data source of all my reports by editing the shared dataset. But I'm always open to better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This might help u .It Represents the collection of data sources referenced from within the body of a report

```
 DataSources("name").Type
```

For detail explanation you can go through the link [Using Global Collections in Expressions (Reporting Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157274%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, my report doesn't reference a data source. Only a shared dataset. The shared dataset is is the one referencing a data source.

Answer (score 0):

An expression like =DataSources!DataSource1.DataSourceReference returns a string value representing the name of a shared data source when applicable. If the data source in the expression is an embedded data source, the expression returns an empty string.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as my data source isn't referenced in the report. I edited my question.